# Exception 'TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null' running dyson mock server (using express.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocking

Running the webpro/dyson-demo (node.js) as a mock server and attempted to return a canned data, for example:

```
module.exports = {
  path: '/query?',
  collection: false,
  template: function(params, query, body, cookies, headers) {
        return cannedJsonFromFile;
    },
```

};

But received the error message (dyson uses Express.js):

> "Potentially unhandled rejection [1] TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: ..." 
>   (bottom of stack):   at c:\dev\projects\noms\navmps.services.demo\dyson-mock-oob-server\dyson-demo\node_modules\dyson\lib\response.js:82:53

Comment: wait... are you deliberately posting question AND answer? don't do that

Comment: @Chris G : why not?

Comment: I see that SO even encourages this, apparently. In that case, go ahead :)

Comment: @ChrisG in this specific case, this is rather not a problem that someone else may have. Its rather the typo kind bug...

Comment: It can be obscure when working with frameworks as to the true nature of the bug, such as in this case where a JS object was required, not a JSON string.  The dyson mock server (github) seems pretty handy, so I'm sure more people will be attempting what I show above.

Answer (score 0):

The canned data was loaded as a JSON string '{...}' and needed to be converted to a an object using JSON.parse:

```
module.exports = {
  path: '/query?',
  collection: false,
  template: function(params, query, body, cookies, headers) {
        return JSON.parse(cannedJsonFromFile);
    },
```

};